# using for each on checkbox's value to fpdf (PHP)

Tags: php, checkbox, fpdf

I'm trying to execute a pdf file where my checkboxes' value will be displayed.
and it did, but when I checked more than 6 checkboxes they goes out of the size of the paper. So I tried using for each statment to limit the value and breaks when the limit number is reached but the PDF won't execute anymore.

this is the code I made.

```
foreach ($_POST['foods_beef'] as $selected_beef)  //foods_beef is the checkbox value
    {
        $x = 1;
        while($flow = $selected_beef->fetch_assoc()) {                                    
            $pdf->Cell(40,5,"$flow - ", 0,0);                                                    
            $x++;
              if($x > 3){  //limit number                        
                    $pdf->Cell(30,5, "", 0,1); //this will happen if limit number is reached
                    $x=1;
                    }                                                      
         }
    }
```

Comment: _"it won't execute anymore"_ - What won't? The script at all or your break? What actually happens when you run your code?

Comment: SInce `$selected_beed` is the value from the checkbox, why are you trying to run the method `fetch_assoc()` on it?  Surely that's a string and not an object, right? Have you checked your servers error log?

Comment: oh sorry, I thought it works that way, since I tried using it on a string too. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: A string is a string, not an object. It doesn't have any methods or properties. `fetch_assoc()` is a method for getting a row as an associated array from a mysqli (database) result after you've done a SQL query. They're not related in anyway at all.